# Filter out parent row if child row present

Tags: r, dplyr, filtering

I've got an interesting filter problem.  For each TEI I need to check if it exists in any CHILDREN_LIST, and if it does delete the parent row where it exists.

For example:  TEI 611100 exists in the CHILDREN_LIST for TEI 611000 so I need to delete the 611000 row.

Here is the dput() for the table.  Thanks!

```
structure(list(TEI = c(611000L, 611100L, 238000L, 452000L, 561000L, 
    621000L, 622000L, 622100L, 623000L, 722000L, 722500L, 722510L
    ), OWNERSHIP = c(30L, 30L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 
    50L, 50L, 50L), RESULT = c(266.9, 259.5, 138, 103.3, 105.8, 130, 
    230, 214.1, 171.9, 204, 185.2, 185.2), CODE = c(3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L), CHILDREN_LIST = structure(c(4L, 
    NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, NA, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("238100 238200 238300 238900", 
    "452100 452900", "561100 561200 561300 561400 561500 561600 561700 561900", 
    "611100 611200", "621100 621200 621300 621400 621500 621600 621900", 
    "622100 622200 622300", "623100 623200 623300 623900", "722300 722400 722500", 
    "722510", "722511 722513 722514 722515"), class = "factor"), 
        ESTIMATE_TYPE = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), NAICS_LABEL = c(611, 6111, 
        238, 452, 561, 621, 622, 6221, 623, 722, 7225, 72251), NAICS_TITLE = structure(c(3L, 
        4L, 11L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 5L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("Administrative and support services", 
        "Ambulatory health care services", "Educational services", 
        "Elementary and secondary schools", "Food services and drinking places", 
        "General medical and surgical hospitals", "General merchandise stores", 
        "Hospitals", "Nursing and residential care facilities", "Restaurants", 
        "Specialty trade contractors"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("TEI", 
    "OWNERSHIP", "RESULT", "CODE", "CHILDREN_LIST", "ESTIMATE_TYPE", 
    "NAICS_LABEL", "NAICS_TITLE"), row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

#Construct a numeric list of children nodes for each row
child_list <- df$CHILDREN_LIST %>% as.character %>% strsplit("\\W+") %>% sapply(as.numeric)

#Test whether a TEI has a child
has_child <- sapply(child_list, function(ch) {
    any(ch %in% df$TEI)
})

subset(df, !has_child)
```

Comment: Awesome response!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by any CHILDREN_LIST, you meant as any element in that particular row's list. 
Here is what I did. I know using for loops in R is not popular, but here it makes the code clearer for me.

```
which_rows_to_delete<-vector()

for ( i in 1:length(a)){
  #first create a vector of all the TEI in the children list 
  children<-unlist(strsplit(as.character(factor(a$CHILDREN_LIST[i])), split=" "))
  #check if the TEI of the row matches any element of the vector
  check<-any(a$TEI[i]==children)&!is.na(a$CHILDREN_LIST[i])
  #store that information in another vector
  which_rows_to_delete[i]<-check
}
a<-a[!check,]
```

Assuming by any CHILDREN_LIST, you meant as any element in that particular row's list. If not, and you need to see if it matches any element in any entry in CHILDREN_LIST column at all, instead of `children` in the above code, use:

```
children_all<-unlist(strsplit(levels(a$CHILDREN_LIST), split=" "))
```

The dput you give does not have any such overlaps, hence the output for this data frame is the same. But this code should work in general. :)